# Is it possible to use single select but get model as an array

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-select2

I am using angular-ui's select2 component and I would like to have consistent values for my models whether I am using single select or multi select.

Currently if I use single select the model is just set to one value, when using multi select the model is an array of values.

IE single select: (non array model)

```
<ui-select ng-model="model.value" theme="bootstrap">
  <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.title}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="choice.title as choice in choices | filter: $select.search">
    <div ng-bind-html="choice.title | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Or multi: (array model)

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="model.value" theme="bootstrap">
  <ui-select-match>{{$item.title}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="choice.title as choice in choices">
    <div ng-bind-html="choice.title"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

I tried using multiple, and adding length="1" attribute, however that still applies the multiselect styles to the select box.

Would it be possible to get an array model back from select2 even on single select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting the model to be the first position in an array by changing ng-model="model.value" to ng-model="model.value[0]"? I believe that should work. If not, try initializing the model in the controller first as an empty array. ($scope.model = [];)

```
<ui-select ng-model="model.value[0]" theme="bootstrap">
  <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.title}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="choice.title as choice in choices | filter: $select.search">
    <div ng-bind-html="choice.title | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: Brilliant idea!